# How to bring this two line variable assignment and comparision down to one line

Tags: ruby

I have two lines of ruby code to strip URLs (string) of certain objects from their specific extension (string) and test and possibly reassign if they match a specific string ('index').

```
page_path = page_object.url_string.chomp(page_object.extension_string)
page_path = '' if page_path == 'index'
```

My actual variable names are different (shorter) of course, the ones above are just for better illustration.

Is it suitable and possible to get this done in one, elegant line of ruby code?

Comment: Don't compromise readability for the sake of brevity. There's nothing elegant about doing that. If you must, focus instead on execution time not some perceived notion of "elegance" via brevity. Brevity of code is only really useful to JavaScript or CSS where it directly impacts page load time (and these days it's really only a concern for mobile browsers).

Comment: Refactoring questions should be asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a possible solution

```
page_path = page_object.url_string.
            chomp(page_object.extension_string).
            sub(/\Aindex\Z/,'')
```

Comment: You'd get a NoMethodError exception if page_object.url_string.chomp(page_object.extension_string) returned a nil object, but giving it a plus vote for being about the only decent solution I could think up as well. (maybe a throw a try block and some ternary operators in there to get it just right). :)

Comment: @zed_0xff Quite nice. Exception handling is outside the scope of this snippet.